# Cannot add reference to program

Tags: c#, reference, class-library

I added a program to my solution and this happens from time to time but not as bad as this time.

It show a yellow triangle as if I do not have a reference; however, I have added a reference about 20 times and it does not add anything to the bin but it does add that triangle reference to the references shown in the snapshot.

This little issue doesn't happen often so when it does i always forget how i fixed it the previous time, but as of now it has my entire solution broken.

Which file it is that points these references the correct way so this error does not happen?

Like mentioned, I add it, look in the bin, not there, look at the references, it's there with a triangle.

FYI, it will do this to any reference i try to add.

I've deleted the program, added it back, it is just a pain.

Please see ElevationMaker

**ElevationMaker is the program i added that you cannot see that i am attempting to add a reference to.**

Thank you very much.

[image: Cannot Add References]

Comment: Try adding reference from the project not from references. Also try cleaning solution and check runtime version ?

Comment: Make sure it is not targeting a higher version of .net framework

Comment: Thanks, that was it, i was targeting the wrong framework

Answer (score 0):

1. Right mouse click on "Solution" -> Clean Solution
2. Close solution
3. Delete *.suo file in the solution directory
4. Open solution
5. Right mouse click on "Solution" -> Rebuild Solution